# Change UICollectionViewCell size according to the size of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionViewController` in storyboard with `Collection Header View`  and one dynamic `UICollectionViewCell`. I add new `cells` progrmatically. I want to build interface as two portrait cell in one row  including image in it and further cell as same. I have added constraints to `Collection Header View` and `UICollectionViewCell`.

It works fine for the device with the screen size that I used for `Storyboard` but does not change its size according to the other screens.

The size of the `UICollectionViewCell` stays same. For example, In `iPhone 4s` only one cell fits and further `cell` below it one by one. In the `iPhone 6s` screen two portrait `cells` in one row but with more gap between them. In `iPhone 6` it fits perfectly because I have used that size for `storyboard`.

I have tried `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` method but again I am giving static size here which stays same and does not change accordingly.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout (UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(160, 256); }
```

Comment: what is your question ? Did you look into autolayout ?

Comment: I do not understand what should I look in autolayout. I am not much familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SELF ANSWER**

The answer I am going to  provide is not feasible, but it works fine for me.

I have used the code shown below to resize `UICollectionViewCell` width according to the `UIView` size.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2.2, 256); }
```

Here static height is fine for me because it allows to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

```
You set the custom method for uicollectionviewlayout for iphone5 and iphone6 etc.Its like above code..

@property (strong,nonatomic)uicollectionviewlayout *objLayout;
[self setlayout];
-(void)setlayout
{
if(iphone5s)
{
  objLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(cellSize, cellSize);
}
else
{
  objLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(cellSize, cellSize);
}
[self.menuCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:objLayout];
}
```